# DateTime Convertions

Tags: apex, datetime, conversion

I have a problem to convert String to DateTime and **Insert** it to a DateTime field in SF.

I found out that this is work :

```
String dateee = '2015/03/10 05:03:20';
DateTime date_time = DateTime.valueOfGmt(dateee.replaceAll('/','-'));
someObject__c someObjectInstance = new someObject__c(someObject_Date__c=date_time);
insert someObjectInstance;
```

But I get the DateTime from a JSON (String) :
"03/10/2015 05:03:20" (dd/mm/yyyy)
And when I put this text inside the code above I get an error of:

```
System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION, someObject: invalid date: Sat Apr 06 05:03:20 GMT 9: [someObject__c]
```

I tried the below code to format it :

```
String dateee = '03/10/2015 05:03:20';
DateTime a = DateTime.valueOfGmt(dateee.replaceAll('/','-'));
a.formatGMT('DD-MM-YYYY\'T\'HH:mm:ss\'Z\'');
System.debug(a);
```

But it dosnt work..

I need to format it and insert it as a DateTime field. 
Can someone please help or post here some links? I tried to look for it but didn't find something valuable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JSON format, use the standard ISO format:

```
YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSSZ
```

For example, from your original value:

```
2015-03-10T05:03:20.000Z
```

Example code (Execute Anonymous):

```
public class JSONStructure {
  public DateTime startDate;
  public DateTime endDate;
}
String jsonExample = '{"startDate":"2018-11-25T03:00:00.000Z","endDate":"2018-11-25T05:00:00.000Z"}';
JSONStructure output = (JSONStructure)JSON.deserialize(jsonExample, JSONStructure.class);
System.debug(output);
```

With output looking like this:

```
USER_DEBUG [7]|DEBUG|JSONStructure:[endDate=2018-11-25 05:00:00, startDate=2018-11-25 03:00:00]
```

Note that the times are in GMT, so if your time values are not, some conversion will be required.

Comment: Hi Thank you for your response. At the JSON I get from the client the next format DD\MM\YYYY - I can get it also as : MM\DD\YYYY. I'm running the below code : ` String dateee = '03/10/2015 05:03:20'; DateTime a = DateTime.valueOfGMT(dateee.replaceAll('/','-')); ` (I tried to use the function just valueOf without the GMT..) and the output is : DEBUG|0009-04-06 05:03:20 and that why the insert of a DateTime field is throw me a DML Ecxeption - I dont sure why its converting it like this way.. and how can it be fix without use the struct : YYYY\MM\DD. thanks @sfdcfox

Comment: @Salvation Let's try this again. If you want to use the JSON class to parse your JSON, use `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSSZ`. If you want to use some other format, you must manually parse the string. Which also means that you need to know your locale to use `DateTime.parse(dateString)`, or you need to use `DateTime.newInstance(year, month, day, hour, minute, second)`, which involves getting the six value parts, using Integer.valueOf to convert them to numbers, and use those to get the final value you'd assign.

Comment: Thank you @sfdcfox,
I just got it.
I somehow confused and thought that if I will insert this format (YYYY-MM-DD) it will insert this format as well in SF DateTime field - But I just figured out that it depends on the local user setting and that why I didn't understand you in the first time.
I will convert his date to this format and insert it to SF.
Many thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

valueOf in place of DateTime.valueOfGmt

String dateee = '2015/03/10 05:03:20';

DateTime date_time = DateTime.valueOf(dateee.replaceAll('/','-'));

someObject__c someObjectInstance = new someObject__c(someObject_Date__c=date_time);

insert someObjectInstance;

hope this help you.

Comment: Yes, that worked for me also as I wrote in the post.
But I get the date in different format: dd/mm/yyyy
and here the issue begins - and I get the DML error.
I don't want to make a function for changing the date to this format - I think there is a better and easy way.. I just didn't find it yet :\
Thanks ! @Nagendra Swami

Comment: the date format depends on user locale setting when you will go to my setting and locale text then there should united states by default that allow (MM/DD/YYYY) format. if you need different format then update the locale setting.

Comment: use this
1. At the top of any Salesforce page, click the down arrow next to your name. From the menu under your name, select Setup or My Settings—whichever one appears.
2. From the left panel, select one of the following:
If you clicked Setup, select My Personal Information | Personal Information.
If you clicked My Settings, select Personal | Advanced User Details.& Time Zone. 
3. Click Edit. 
4. Change the locale to the desired region.

Comment: Thank you! I got my mistake here as I replayed to sfdcfox.
Thanks !!

Comment: Can't Mark 2 answers as best answers but this one helped me also. Thank you!